# FORM POST TO EXTERNAL URL -NEED HTTP BUT ALWAYS IN HTTPS-

Tags: forms, http, https, salesforce-lightning

In a AURA Lightining component,i need to implement a POST with a FORM, and the target Endpoint is in HTTP and not in HTTPS.

Here the code:

on submitForm:

cmp.find("formFirma").getElement().submit();

The problem is that when i click on button,the browser open the new tab always in https and doesn't find the external resource.
Even if POST should be always in HTTPS,is there a way to this HTTP?

if a do a "GET" with :

'''
 var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": "http://endpoint"
        });

```
    urlEvent.fire();
```

'''

it works in HTTP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div onclick="{!c.submitForm}">
            <form name="formFirma1" target="_blank"  forceSSL="false" aura:id="formFirma"  action="http://endpoint" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="idVerbale" value="191" />
                <input type="hidden" name="CUAA" value="12345AB" />
                <input type="hidden" name="TipoUtente" value="Agronomo" />
                <lightning:button label="Firma" />
            </form></div>
```

Here is the markup